# Parse core cordova ionic global variable

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I have a small application where i use parse core as the backend.

```
  $scope.getPeople = function(params) {
    var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(PeopleObject);
    if(params !== undefined) {
        if(params.id !== undefined) {
            query.equalTo("objectId", params.id);
        }

    }
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            //alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " people!");
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                  $scope.admin=object.get("admin");
                  $scope.uid=object.id;

            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

};
```

The problem is i need to get `$scope.admin` and `$scope.uid` outside the function.
I have another function called `getlogin()` where i call `$scope.getPeople()` i need both the variables in `getlogin()` too.. if i add a return inside the success function of `getPeople()` it returns undefined. I need something so that i can get both the variables returned from the function..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values after calling `$scope.getPeople()`, you should wrap the inner code in a promise like object and resolve that object when you have the two values. In the calling location, you can access the values by chaining `.then()` after the call to this function.

For eg, something like:

```
$scope.getPeople = function(params) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(PeopleObject);
    if(params !== undefined) {
        if(params.id !== undefined) {
            query.equalTo("objectId", params.id);
        }

    }
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            //alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " people!");
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                  $scope.admin=object.get("admin");
                  $scope.uid=object.id;

                  defer.resolve({admin: object.get("admin"), uid: object.id})
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Note: This should resolve your problem but you might want to use the .first() method on the query instead of the .find() method if you just need to retrieve one value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the LocalStorage or SessionStorage?

SessionStorage maintains the value when you navigating in the Site (across the pages in same URL)

LocalStorage persists the value until you clean it or clean browser.

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('myKey', myObj);
```

to get:

```
var item = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
```

HTH
Gabriel